# adjust character order of file names (batch)

Tags: scripts, batch-rename

I have several files named by date and I am trying to make a batch change in naming

they look like this:

```
dd-mm-yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy or ddjanyyyy
```

and I'm trying to standardize everyone like this:

```
yyyy-mm-dd-file-name-default
```

Comment: Are those files all in one folder? Which programming language do you prefer the solution to your problem? Bash, Python or Go? If you want to try yourself, I can recommend https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter9/

Answer (score 0):

If you really only need to "adjust character order" then it's fairly straightforward with the Perl-based `rename` command, using capture groups and backreferencing.

Ex. given

```
$ ls
000000  02jan1999  19.11.2017  23-11-2012  file
```

then

```
$ rename -n 's/(\d{2})[-.](\d{2})[-.](\d{4})/$3-$2-$1-file-name-default/' *
rename(19.11.2017, 2017-11-19-file-name-default)
rename(23-11-2012, 2012-11-23-file-name-default)
```

OTOH if you want to do date conversions like `jan` --> `01`, then it's a bit more complicated. You could write your own lookup table using a hash, or make use of the `strptime` and `strftime` methods provided by the `Time::Piece` module:

```
$ rename -n '
  BEGIN{use Time::Piece}; 
  my $dt;
  eval {
    $dt = Time::Piece->strptime($_,"%d-%m-%Y");
  } or do { 
    eval {
      $dt = Time::Piece->strptime($_,"%d.%m.%Y");
    } or do {
      eval {
        $dt = Time::Piece->strptime($_,"%d%b%Y");
      } or return;
    }
  };
  $_ = $dt->strftime("%Y-%m-%d-file-name-default")
' *
rename(02jan1999, 1999-01-02-file-name-default)
rename(19.11.2017, 2017-11-19-file-name-default)
rename(23-11-2012, 2012-11-23-file-name-default)
```